# scope of nested R function

Tags: r, nested, lexical-scope, referential-transparency

I have an example where I am  not sure I understand scoping in R, nor I think it's doing the Right Thing. The example is modified from "An R and S-PLUS Companion to Applied Regression" by J. Fox

```
> make.power = function(p) function(x) x^p
> powers = lapply(1:3, make.power)
> lapply(powers, function(p) p(2))
```

What I expected in the list powers where three functions that compute the identity, square and cube functions respectively, but they all cube their argument. If I don't use an lapply, it works as expected.

```
> id = make.power(1)
> square = make.power(2)
> cube = make.power(3)
> id(2)
[1] 2
> square(2)
[1] 4
> cube(2)
[1] 8
```

Am I the only person to find this surprising or disturbing? Is there a deep satisfying reason why it is so? Thanks

PS: I have performed searches on Google and SO, but, probably due to the generality of the keywords related to this problem, I've come out empty handed.

PPS: The example is motivated by a real bug in the package quickcheck, not by pure curiosity. I have a workaround for the bug, thanks for your concern. This is about learning something.

After posting the question of course I get an idea for a different example that could clarify the issue.

```
> p = 1
> id = make.power(p)
> p = 2
> square = make.power(p)
> id(2)
[1] 4
```

p has the same role as the loop variable hidden in an lapply. p is passed by a method that in this case looks like reference to make.power. Make.power doesn't evaluate it, just keeps a pointer to it.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes the problem

```
make.power = function(p) {force(p); function(x) x^p}
powers = lapply(1:3, make.power)
lapply(powers, function(p) p(2))
```

This issue is that function parameters are passed as "promises" that aren't evaluated until they are actually used. Here, because you never actually use `p` when calling `make.power()`, it remains in the newly created environment as a promise that points to the variable passed to the function. When you finally call `powers()`, that promise is finally evaluated and the most recent value of `p` will be from the last iteration of the `lapply`. Hence all your functions are cubic.

The `force()` here forces the evaluation of the promise. This allows the newly created function each to have a different reference to a specific value of `p`.